# How to Send Message to all Users In Openfire?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

I want to send message to all users in openfire . I have knew the  Broadcast Plugin . But it can send message to only online users . But i want to send message to all users of openfires . Please help me out is there is any plug in or other way to send message to all users .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official specifications, just use Broadcast Plugin configuring it properly with this param:

```
plugin.broadcast.all2offline -- true to deliver broadcast messages sent to all@[serviceName].[serverName] to online and offline users. When false or not set only online users get the messages as described below.
```

So just add this parameter

- by Admin Console panel (Server -> System Properties -> "Add new
  property" on bottom )
- or by adding this value on OFPROPERTY table on database.

An Openfire restart can be required.